# Wordpress menus shows changed items only to logged in user

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress website where i have a problem. I need to change the main menu and remove some entries, theese entries are removed only for logged in users, if i go to the website as anonymous user i see the original menu with all elements. I'm going crazy.

Comment: Caching plugin?

Answer (score 0):

use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/,

or you can use "is_admin" in four functions.php too.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you will need to remove those items from your menu and then please place the following code in your functions.php file, and replace the items and links

```
function add_login_logout_register_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location != 'primary' ) {
        return $items;
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="item1 url">'. __("item1") .'</a></li>';
        $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="item1 url">'. __("item1") .'</a></li>';
    } 
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_register_menu', 199, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

i already installed "IF MENU" plugin, but it didn't work for my website, so i removed id. after that, i cannot update the "anonymous" menu anymore (it seems to happen mainly in the home page). It seems that IF MENU broken my website